# Mongodb get average rating from nested array with moviename

Tags: arrays, mongodb, average

I am new to MongoDB. I have a collection of movies like shown in figure [image: collection_image]

Some movie has MoveiReview while some doensot has MovieReview yet. What i want is to list average rating of the movie and its name of all movie.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ba65d9cdfbc44415d0edaec"),
    "MovieName": "King Kong"
    "avgAge" : 9.0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ba65d9cdfbc44415d0edaec"),
    "MovieName": "King Kong"
    "avgAge" : 9.0
}
```

i tried the following code but only got id with average rating.

```
db.movies.aggregate([

    { $unwind: "$MovieReview" },
    { $group : { _id: "$_id", avgRating : {  $avg : "$MovieReview.Rating" }}},

]);
```

Result

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ba65d9cdfbc44415d0edaec"),
    "avgRating" : 9.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ba65d9cdfbc44415d0edaeb"),
    "avgRating" : 10.0
}
```

I think the solution is simple but i am not being able to figure out Or i am not aware of what to look for. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: use `$first` aggregation for the `MovieName`... Like `MovieName: { '$first': '$MovieName' }`

Comment: thanks got it. and what if i want movie which dont have review yet with average rating 0

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem that you have not MovieName in result? If so, you should modify your code like this

```
db.movies.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$MovieReview" 
  },
  { 
    $group : { 
      _id: "$_id", 
      MovieName: { $first: "$MovieName" }, 
      avgRating : {  $avg : "$MovieReview.Rating" }
    }
  },
```

]);

Answer (score 0):

Grouping by `_id` is pointless in this case. If all the ratings you need to calculate the average are contained in a single document's `MovieRating` array then this is what you want:

```
db.movies.aggregate({
    $addFields: {
        avgRating: { $avg: "$MovieReview.Rating" }
    }
})
```